# Armhf chroot on arm64

Tags: server, arm, chroot

First off should I not be able to run armhf on an arm64 server without needing qemu? or am I wrong there? If i run a armhf app I get this: `Exec format error`

I have been trying to setup and armhf chroot with qemu on my arm64 server with no success.
I have tried `qemu-debootstrap --arch armhf xenial build`

But I always run into this issue, with or without qemu:

```
I: Running command: chroot build /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
chroot: failed to run command ‘/debootstrap/debootstrap’: Exec format error
```

For some reason it seems like it's not using "qemu-user-static" at all
Because if i run `qemu-arm-static build/bin/echo` it works just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds as if you need to file a bug report ;)

Comment: There is a detailed guide here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch/QemuDebootstrap . Did you run the "First stage debootstrap" ?

Comment: Yes i did, first stage goes fine, but the problem starts when it tried to enter the rootfs and do second stage.